# Retrieving Result From Function (Swift/WatchOS 2)

Tags: swift, function, watchos-2

I'm having an issue that very well may be a conceptual problem, but am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  I am trying to receive a dictionary of data from an iOS app in my WatchKit extension, using the new WCSession * didReceiveMessage*.  When I print the received message, I am properly receiving the data, but I am unable to do anything with this data outside of the function (such as populate a WKInterfaceTable, which is my end goal).

**InterfaceController.swift (WatchOS):**

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

var session : WCSession!
var files = [String]()

@IBOutlet var fileTable: WKInterfaceTable!

override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    // Configure interface objects here.
    startSession()
    reloadTable()
}

private func startSession() {
    if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
        session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
        print("activated session")
    }
}

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()   
}

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let files = message["myFiles"] as? String
    print(files!)
    reloadTable()

}

func reloadTable() {
    print("Test: \(files)")

    fileTable.setNumberOfRows(files.count, withRowType: "FileTableRowController")

    for (index, file) in files.enumerate() {
        if let row = fileTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as? FileTableRowController {

            row.fileLabel.setText("test")
        }
    }
}
```

**TableViewController.swift (iOS):**

```
...
let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
                print("Session is reachable: \(session.reachable)") // this is false
                let msg = ["myFiles":String(self.files)]
                session.sendMessage(msg, replyHandler: { reply in
                    print("Got reply: \(reply)")
                    }, errorHandler: { error in
                        print("error: \(error)")
                })
...
```

It seems as though that after WatchKit receives `files` and properly prints it, that variable is not being populated elsewhere.  Thus, I can't reload the table, or even print within the `reloadTable()` function, despite my best efforts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you aren't assigning files to your class variable, so it is getting released before you want it to. dispatch_async should also be used when reloading the UI.

I think the main issue here is you are trying to send your custom FileData object as a string in a dictionary, but you are doing this by getting the string value of the object, which will not work. You need to add some custom serialization of your object to be able to convert it to a dictionary that can be sent in the message payload. Here is an example of how to do that with a test class that has two properties:

```
internal class Testing: NSObject {

    var name: String
    var someNumber: NSNumber

    init(name: String, someNumber: NSNumber) {
        self.name = name
        self.someNumber = someNumber
    }

    func serialize() -> [String:AnyObject] {
        var transfer = [String:AnyObject]()
        transfer["name"] = self.name
        transfer["someNumber"] = self.someNumber
        return transfer
    }

    class func deserialize(transfer: [String:AnyObject]) -> Testing {
        let deserialized = Testing(
            name: transfer["name"] as! String,
            someNumber:transfer["someNumber"] as! NSNumber)

        return deserialized
    }
}
```

You can then use this to send a message as follows from your iOS controller:

```
...
let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
                let testing = Testing(name: "my name", someNumber: 1)
                let serializedTesting = testing.serialize()
                let msg = ["myFiles":serializedTesting]
                session.sendMessage(msg, replyHandler: { reply in
                    print("Got reply: \(reply)")
                    }, errorHandler: { error in
                        print("error: \(error)")
                })
...
```

And you can read the message as follows from your watch OS controller:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject]) {
    // Pull out the serialized object
    let files = message["myFiles"] as? [String:AnyObject]

    // Deserialize back to object
    self.files = Testing.deserialize(serializedTesting)

    // Update the UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        reloadTable()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Some confusion seems to be occurring around how to send custom objects between an iOS app and watchOS app. Apple's documentation shows that we need to either cover the objects into an NSDate or serialize our custom objects into an NSDictionary that ONLY CONTAINS FOUNDATION TYPES (NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, etc.) before sending it. This can cause a lot of overhead for a developer even if they have just a few simple custom objects that are related to each other.

In order to ease this pain in my own projects, I have created a generic serializer/deserializer class using swift 2.0 that is very simple to use and designed with communication between iOS and watchOS.

Each custom class you want to transfer just needs to extend the Serializable class and add an @objc tag at the top of the class. The Testing class I used as an example above would then become:

```
@objc(Testing)
internal class Testing: Serializable {
    var name: String
    var someNumber: NSNumber
}
```

It is available on [github here](https://github.com/lehn0058/SwiftSerializable) and contains a playground with working examples.

Comment: Thanks @lehn0058.  I understand what you're saying about the class variable, though I'm unsure exactly how to go about fixing it (since I can't seem to cast my files [String] as to be files [FileData].  I did try your suggestion of changing the line to `self.files = message["myFiles"] as? [String]`, though Xcode made me change this to `self.files = (message["myFiles"] as? [String])!`, which is giving me a `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x4d9d6c) to 'NSArray' (0x4da154)` error when I build.

Comment: What is self.files in your iOS controller? Is it just an NSString, or a collection of strings?

Comment: Hi @lehn0058.  At the top of my iOS TableViewController, I have `var files = [FileData]()`.  FileData is a custom class (it's a NSObject) that holds two strings; fileName and fileType.  Both of these strings are being set via a NSURL request and some XML parsing that sets them appropriately.  Does that help?  :)

Comment: Ah! That makes more sense. String(self.files) will not serialize your object the way you are hoping. This is the "toString" of the object. I have updated my answer with a (hopefully) more appropriate response.

Comment: Hi @lehn0058!  I've _almost_ gotten this to work!  Using your above example, I am getting the iOS app to pass `Testing(name: "my name", someNumber: 1)` to the WatchKit app.  But, if I assign `var tests = [Testing]()` at the top of my controller and try to do `let testing = self.tests` (which should be a dictionary of data confirming to the Testing class), I receive an error that [Testing] does not have a member named 'serialize.'  Is there another way I would append my instances of name and someNumber to a Testing dictionary?

Comment: [Testing] is an array of Testing objects. The serialize method only exists on the Testing object, so you can't call it on the array. If you really want to have an array of testing objects, then you would need to loop through each one, call the serialize method for each item, and put those results into a separate dictionary. I think you want var tests: Testing! at the top of your controller

Comment: Thanks, @lehn0058.  I get what you're saying, though I'm struggling to put my serialized results in a new dictionary.  At a conceptual level, I'm confused as to whether I'm overcomplicating this.  It seems like downloading data from a web service as JSON or XML, saving to a dictionary, and passing all of the downloaded data to WatchKit would be a very common thing for developers.  I seem to be struggling with why passing multiple pieces of data (like a dictionary of JSON or XML) would be so complex, though perhaps it's an error in my concept.

Answer (score 2):

The WCSessionDelegate methods and block handlers are called on a serial background queue, so if you want to update the UI you will have to dispatch to the main queue first

Comment: Thanks @ccjensen, always helpful!  I did try to add a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.reloadTable())
        })` in the WCsession function, but it still doesn't seem to be passing the "files" dictionary to the table itself.  Maybe I did that wrong?

Comment: @Lehn0058 seems to be right. In addition to the dispatch you need to store the files dictionary in your instance variable

Comment: I agree, though I've been unsuccessful is using @lehn0058's suggestion at the moment.  I updated my original message with the iOS side of things; perhaps I'm sending the data wrong and that's the root of it after all?  I conceptually understand the issue, but can't seem to fathom how to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks for your constant help, but I think the bigger issue here is why I'm saving my data to a custom class rather than just a dictionary.  As such, I think it's best I write a new question trying to understand the dictionary approach so it can be passed natively.

Answer (score 1):

One thing i can suggest over here is files variable will not be accessible from read table method , please try to pass files variable to readtable function

Also since you have defined files by Let (virtually static) so what is need of reload table? since files wont be changed in this case.

you might try to define files as variable at higher level where fileTable is decleared.

Please let me know if that works